# How this code works "head->next = second;"?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *second;
    struct node *third;
    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    second = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    third = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->data = 1;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 2;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 3;
    head->next = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

I didn't get how the next got the value of second?? I mean I don't got the sequence, does it means the value of second goes in next and head points to next?

Comment: those are pointers, what is cpied is not the node itself but its address

Answer (score 1):

It work like this:

```
head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
second = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
third = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Assuming all `malloc` are success, the in-memory view would be something like this -

```
  head---+
         |
        +-------+
        |   |   |
        +-------+

second---+
         |
        +-------+
        |   |   |
        +-------+

 third---+
         |
        +-------+
        |   |   |
        +-------+

====================================

head->data = 1;
head->next = second;

// After execution of these statements

  head---+
         |
        +-------+
        | 1 |   |---+
        +-------+   |        // now memory referred by pointer second
                    |        // is also referred by head->next pointer
second---+ +--------+
         | | 
        +-------+
        |   |   |
        +-------+

 third---+
         |
        +-------+
        |   |   |
        +-------+

====================================

second->data = 2;
second->next = third;

// After execution of these statements

  head---+
         |
        +-------+
        | 1 |   |---+
        +-------+   |        // second->data == head->next->data
                    |
second---+ +--------+
         | | 
        +-------+
        | 2 |   |---+
        +-------+   |        // now memory referred by pointer third
                    |        // is also referred by second->next pointer
 third---+ +--------+
         | | 
        +-------+
        |   |   |
        +-------+


====================================

third->data = 3;
head->next = NULL;     // did you mean third->next = NULL !

// After execution of these statements

  head---+
         |
        +-------+
        | 1 |   |--->NULL    // head->next = NULL will break the link 
        +-------+            // between pointer and memory area it was
                             // referring to
second---+ 
         |  
        +-------+
        | 2 |   |---+
        +-------+   |
                    |
 third---+ +--------+
         | | 
        +-------+
        | 3 |   |
        +-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Each struct node is a data structure that has two variables:

- An integer value
- A pointer to another node struct

Essentially, with the following instruction, the "next" variable of the node named "head", will take the address of the node named "second":

```
head->next = second;
```

Answer (score 0):

`head` is a pointer to a struct which you dynamically allocated with `malloc`.

`head->next` is just a shortcut for `(*head).next`.

`head` is accessing a member of the structure it is pointing to, and setting it to point to `second`, which is a pointer to a `struct` of the same type `head` is pointing to. The document you found this code in, explains it in detail.

*Aside:*
The cast is redundant. `C` automatically promotes the `void` pointer returned to the correct type.
You should also be checking the return value of `malloc` to see if it succeeded. Attempting to dereference an indeterminate or `NULL` pointer has undefined behaviour.